# Django queryset with recursive many-to-many and result displayed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I would like to get your help in order to find a solution to my issue by handling many-to-many field and display the result.

**Expected result:**

I have a list of content version in my application (e.g : 8th Edition, 9th Edition, 10th Edition...) and for each one, I have a list of collections with subversion (toto 9.8, toto 9.9, toto 9.10, toto 10.0, ...).

I'm trying to display a dynamical navbar which contains tabs according to content version. Each tab contains list of subversions.

Tab **9th Edition** contains **9.8, 9.9, 9.10, ...**

Tab **10th Edition** contains **10.0, ...**

**---------**

**My model**:

I have a **model file** which has:

```
class NavbarMenuSettings(models.Model):
    """ A class to manage navbar menu of the application """
    collection = models.ManyToManyField('publication.Collection', related_name='collection_list', symmetrical=False)
    application = models.ForeignKey('publication.WebApplication', verbose_name=_('application'), related_name='application', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=_('title'), default=('Xth Edition (Current)'))
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, verbose_name=_('menu order'), blank=True, null=False)
    display = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Display menu'), default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('menu setting')
        verbose_name_plural = _('menu settings')
```

I have a **menu.py** file which let to handle my navbar:

```
def list_of_edition():
    """ Return list of editions """
    instance = NavbarMenuSettings.objects.filter(display=True).order_by('order')
    return instance

edition_children = ()
for instance in list_of_edition():
    edition_children += MenuItem(instance.collection.all(), reverse('home'), weight=150, separator=False),


for instance in list_of_edition():
    Menu.add_item('edition', MenuItem(instance.title, '#', children=edition_children))
```

I'm trying to make it dynamical. It creates a new tab for each NavbarMenuSettings object displayed. But in each tab, I get the list of all subversions, or I want to display for each tab only subversion(s) associated.

**My test:**

If I write this test:

```
for element in list_of_edition():
    print(element.title)
    print(element.collection.all())
```

It displays:

```
10th Edition (Current)
<QuerySet [<Collection: 10.0 lite>]>
9th Edition
<QuerySet [<Collection: 9.8 lite>, <Collection: 9.9 lite>, <Collection: 9.10 lite>]>
```

But How I can handle my menu in order to display each tab version with list of associated subversions ?

I'm blocked on this step.

Thank you

Comment: You want to show this in template yes ?

Comment: @gd8 You're right, but for the moment, I don't overcome to display tabs with good subversions.

Comment: in public collection model there are 9.1, 9.2 versions ?

Comment: Not mandatory, 9th Edition contains versions beginning by 9.X, 10th Edition contains versions beginnning by 10.X. But it could be Y.1, Y.12, subversions. What I don't overcome is to group subversions to the good version and display on each version tab, only subversions associated.

Comment: I mean ? How do you know 9.1, 9.2, 9.3 are subversion of 9 ? How they are created on the database level ? You have NavbarMenuSettings model, but what about Collection model ? They are used for what ?

Comment: Collection model is a list of content with a specific version for each collection (9.1, 9.2, ...). Then my application knows subversions associated to version because with NavbarMenuSettings model, I check all collection according to a specific version. For example, I create a tab named `9th Edition` and I add all collections with version `9.x`. That's why I have a ManyToManyField collection in my NavbarMenuSettings model. Hopefully it's a little more clear ? ;)

Comment: See,,, I add answer and let me know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
od = OrderedDict()
for version in list_of_edition():
    #print(element.title)
    #print(element.collection.all())
    od.setdefault((version.pk, version.title) []).extend([(subversion.pk, subversion.title) for subversion in version.collection.all()])
print(od)
```

Try this code. Let us know what problem will be.

Comment: It displays `OrderedDict([(2, [58464]), (1, [21928, 29235, 36542])])` which seems to group subversions id to right version id. Now, we have to see How it's possible to rewrite menu tabs by adding title for example.

Comment: I updated answer... Let me know if your problem is solved.

Comment: The result is as expected, but How I can integrate your code to `Menu.add_item` and `MenuItem` which let to display my navbar ?

Comment: This case mark as solved,,,

What you mean exactly ? You want to show this in your html template ?

Comment: `Menu.add_item` and `MenuItem` let to display menu in generic html template. SO my question is : how I can render your code to mine.

Comment: I do not know what is your Menu and MenuItem,,, I will tell you what you need.
In your view function render template and pass your variable (od) and iterate over od variable in your template using django template language.

Comment: I will try and I will come back if I need the solution. Anyway thank you very much for your help !

Comment: You are welcome,,,
but i will advice you to learn about application framework in django. Because make query on a single request because of menu is bad idea. good luck !

Comment: Just a last question if I can disturbe you one more time. How do you access to subversions for a specific version through your dict ?

Comment: This moment you can not,,, As a key now we have (version.pk, version.title),,,

You can change strategy now and generate (version.pk, version.title, version.order)... or just find using title inside dict (first find key) and then value.

Comment: I don't really understand How but I will continue to search. Thank you